# YouTube API for MP4 URL

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I haven't found in the documentation, but wanted to see if anybody knew if the API provides ability to pull an accessible MP4 URL that I can embed in my mobile app. The only link I see if an embedded iframe to put on website. Assuming this does not exist as YouTube wants you to use their player, but just wanted to make sure I was not missing some API that I was unaware of.

Comment: Did you find anything ?

Comment: YouTube doesn't provide access to the raw MP4 video because YouTube runs freely thanks to ads and access such a raw MP4 would be a way of bypassing these ads.